# I try to ftrace open system call but trace record is all about SyS_read

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, system-calls, ext4, ftrace

I tried to trace the `open()` system call using this code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char *path = "/home/[my account]/text.txt";

    int fd;
    fd = open(path, O_RDWR);

    return 0;
}
```

And I compiled it with

```bash
gcc -o open open.c
```

And started to Ftrace.

```bash
echo SyS_open > set_graph_function
```

```bash
echo SyS_read >> set_graph_function
```

```bash
sh -c 'echo $$ > set_ftrace_pid; echo 1 > tracing_on;
exec /home/[my account]/open'
```

And what I got with `cat trace` is only about `SyS_read`.. There is nothing related to `SyS_open`..

(I check with cat set_graph_function like below :

```bash
root@[server name]:/sys/kernel/debug/tracing# cat set_graph_function
SyS_read
SyS_open
```

And confirm that `SyS_open` is not missed.)

```
# CPU  DURATION                  FUNCTION CALLS
# |     |   |                     |   |   |   |
 17)               |  SyS_read() {
 17)               |    __fdget_pos() {
 17)   0.137 us    |      __fget_light();
 17)   1.285 us    |    }
 17)               |    vfs_read() {
 17)               |      rw_verify_area() {
 17)               |        security_file_permission() {
 17)               |          apparmor_file_permission() {
 17)               |            common_file_perm() {
 17)   0.041 us    |              aa_file_perm();
 17)   0.493 us    |            }
 17)   0.934 us    |          }
 17)   0.040 us    |          __fsnotify_parent();
 17)   0.042 us    |          fsnotify();
 17)   2.843 us    |        }
 17)   3.194 us    |      }
 17)               |      __vfs_read() {
 17)               |        new_sync_read() {
 17)               |          ext4_file_read_iter() {
 17)               |            generic_file_read_iter() {
 17)               |              _cond_resched() {
 17)   0.040 us    |                rcu_all_qs();
 17)   0.387 us    |              }
 17)               |              pagecache_get_page() {
 17)   0.225 us    |                find_get_entry();
 17)   0.573 us    |              }
 17)   0.046 us    |              mark_page_accessed();
 17)               |              _cond_resched() {
 17)   0.040 us    |                rcu_all_qs();
 17)   0.393 us    |              }
 17)               |              touch_atime() {
 17)               |                __atime_needs_update() {
 17)               |                  current_time() {
 17)   0.042 us    |                    current_kernel_time64();
 17)   0.039 us    |                    timespec_trunc();
 17)   0.972 us    |                  }
 17)   1.321 us    |                }
 17)   1.692 us    |              }
 17)   4.990 us    |            }
 17)   5.351 us    |          }
 17)   5.766 us    |        }
 17)   6.161 us    |      }
 17)   0.039 us    |      __fsnotify_parent();
 17)   0.045 us    |      fsnotify();
 17) + 10.735 us   |    }
 17) + 13.187 us   |  }
```

Why there is only `SyS_read` even though I write a code with `open()` ?

I tried to drop caches and did it again but the result was exactly the same.

And also I have know idea why `SyS_read` showed up despite the fact that I only used `open()`.

Comment: Are you really exec'ing the .c file instead of the executable file (`exec /home/[my account]/open.c`)?

Comment: Oh that s a typo sorry. I exec executable file. I edited it.

Comment: can you please post your exact kernel version ? `uname -r` ?

Comment: can you check output for ```sh -c 'echo $$ > set_ftrace_pid; echo 1 > tracing_on;
exec cat /home/[my account]/text.txt' ```